# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django', when I run tests

Tags: django, pycharm, django-testing

When I run the `tests` (in the `pycharm` environment) I get an error *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'*. `Django installed (2.2.5)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/projects/slack_bot/tests.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.models import *
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/projects/slack_bot/app/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: How did you install django?

Comment: @JohnGordon `pip install django`

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version`

Comment: pip 19.2.3 from /home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/slack_bot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Comment: That's odd.  Usually this sort of problem is caused by a version mismatch between pip and python, but it looks like you're using 3.6 for both.

Comment: Can you run this code in python and show us the output `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: ['', '/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/slack_bot/lib/python36.zip', '/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/slack_bot/lib/python3.6', '/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/slack_bot/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/slack_bot/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Comment: Interestingly, this error only occurs when running tests. Launch them from `pycharm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have not configured your PyCharm Project to use your virtualenv for tests.

1. In your Run/Debug configurations (the dropdown next to the run button), select "Edit Configurations".
2. Find your test configuration and check the value for "Python Interpreter". If should be something like `/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/slack_bot/bin/python`, but probably it is something like `/usr/bin/python3.6`
3. If it is in the list, select `/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/slack_bot/bin/python`. Otherwise, you have to add a new interpreter.

To add an interpreter, look at the status bar on the bottom right. It should say "Python 3.6". If you click on it, there should be an option to add an interpreter.